# Is there any way to get a path to a file in the GUI in Yosemite?

Tags: finder, macos, file, path

In Mavericks it was simple: click "Get Info" on any file and you could copy/paste the file path. This is no longer included in Yosemite.

I need to need to copy/paste paths frequently, like "/Users/Whoever/MyPath/File.app".

Is there any way to do this in Yosemite without resorting to the terminal?

Comment: Take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/829295/how-to-copy-unix-file-path-in-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drag the file into a Safari window and copy the path from the URL bar. Or drag the file into a Plain Text file in Text Edit. (As you can also do with Terminal.)
EDIT: Safari will only accept certain types. Use a Text Edit file instead.